# How to define query in solr

Tags: join, solr

I am making a log searching service for business by `solr`.

I have some problem during query configuration.

I have below data.

```
 message_type, mobile_no, ident_no, resultCode
||CCR, 01012345678, 1, null||    
||CCA, null, 1, 5012||
```

I want to find all records with same ident_no by using mobile_no.

So, I am thinking sql statement like below.

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM DATA
WHERE IDENT_NO IN (SELECT IDENT_NO FROM DATA WHERE MOBILE_NO = ‘01012345678’)
```

I defined below query for solr.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q={!join from=ident_no to=ident_no}mobile_no:01012345678
```

I didn’t receive the result by using query.
Is this query incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added field mobile number in your schema.xml,then you can fetch the result by using query as  mobile number : 1234567890